# Eclipse CDT Error in GDB debugger target is null

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt, mingw-w64

I want to debug my test.out program with the the gdb debugger from mingw. Calling the gdb debugger with the image file is running successful on the terminal window, but every time I started the debugger from eclipse I got the
****Error message from debugger back end:
You can't do that when your target is `None'
Failed to execute MI command:
load C:\Temp\test.out**
The gdb commander was configured as path/gdb.exe and image and symbol files are the out file.
In the debugger console view I only see the the information about the installed gdb version simular the output that I got when I type only gdb in the terminal window. No MI command.
Any hints how I can solve my problem or find more informatio about it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I was too stupid. I configured my debug configuration as gdb hardware debugger, but since it is a c-application, I have to configure it as such one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).